# Cannot access the function inside the other function

Tags: javascript

This is how my inventoryList() function is called and I cannot change it.

```
 if (operationInfo[0] === 'add') {
            inventoryList().add(operationInfo[1]);
```

But I have a method inside my inventoryList function like below but it states obj.add is not a function! why?

```
function inventoryList(){

    const add = (name) => {
        // adds string to inv and if item exists doesn't add. Adds to log also as objects maintain no position
        if(!(name in inv)){
            inv[name] = name;
            entries.push(name)
        }
      };
}
```

Comment: Could you share the full code ? This is not clear to help you . what is obj?

Comment: sure will update thakn you so much

Comment: does that help? the issue is it does recognise the add method? I think i need to return somewhere?

Comment: Your `inventoryList` should return `add` method in order to use it somewhere outside of that function.

Comment: how could I do that exactly @radovix? I have tried return add; at the ned of add arrow function

Comment: try something like   `this.add  = function(name) { ... } `

Comment: @Tony I posted the answer.

Comment: @Tony , for this kind of requirement using JS classes .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the `add` function, you should return if from your `inventoryList` function.

```
function inventoryList() {
   const add = (name) => {
      if (!(name in inv)) {
         inv[name] = name;
         entries.push(name)
      }
   };

   return { add };
}
```

Althought, if you are going to use it like that, I recommend changing the `inventoryList` to class with `add` as its method.

```
class InventoryList {
   add(name) {
      if (!(name in inv)) {
         inv[name] = name;
         entries.push(name)
      } 
   }
}
```

You can than use it like this

```
const invList = new InventoryList();

if (operationInfo[0] === 'add') {
   invList.add(operationInfo[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you I think this worked.  Would I return more than one function out like this? {add, getList} etc

Comment: Yes you can, but I'm not sure that it is the right approach. I think classes would suit you more.

Comment: I agree with you a class makes way more sense but have never seen / forgotten how to actually return multiple functions out of the parent function! regardless your solution was great. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

`inventoryList` is not returning anything. Return an object which contains reference to the function you want to execute. Also `_add` is an inner function which is private to `inventoryList` so have to expose it to use it

```js
function execute() {
  inventoryList().add('hello')
}

function inventoryList() {
  const _add = (name) => {
    console.log(name)
    // rest of code
  };
  return {
    add: _add,
    // add other function if it is there
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick='execute()'>Execute</button>
```